# android - call fragment method from activity returns null object reference

Tags: android, fragment

calling fragment method from activity returns null object reference, why ?

**Fragment:**

```
private RelativeLayout waitingForTerminal;
private RelativeLayout blackContent;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waiting_for_terminal, container, false);
    setViews(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
private void setViews(View view){
    waitingForTerminal = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.waiting_for_terminal);
    blackContent = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.blank_content);
}

public void hideWaitingForTerminal(){
    waitingForTerminal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    blackContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public void run() {
    WaitingForTerminalFragment fragment = new WaitingForTerminalFragment();
    fragment.hideWaitingForTerminal();

    showToast(terminalConnectionEvent.getTerminalInformation().getSerialNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it.

Fragment:

```
public void hideWaitingForTerminal(View view) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.waiting_for_terminal);
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
private void changeWaitingForTerminalLayout(WaitingForTerminalFragment waitingForTerminalFragment){
    waitingForTerminalFragment.hideWaitingForTerminal(this.findViewById(R.id.terminal).getRootView());
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I still don't understand why everything would always be null when its hosting method is called from an activity did you figure it out eventually?

Answer (score 0):

try by giving the refrence :

```
WaitingForTerminalFragment fragment = (WaitingForTerminalFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youfragmentid);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

Comment: I get -> "fragment : null" when I debug

Comment: you are using getSupportFragmentManager(); or getFragmentManager() in your application

Comment: yes im using getSupportFragmentManager() in MainActivity

Comment: than use    WaitingForTerminalFragment fragment = (WaitingForTerminalFragment)getSupportFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.youfragmentid);

Comment: When I use getSupportFragmentManager()  it returns null.

Comment: plz check a fragment ID you provide is correct in R.id.Fragmentid

Answer (score 0):

By only creating object of that fragment will not call the oncreateview of that fragment class where your view is initialized. This is reason the view inside your fragment method returns `null`.

Call your fragment method from Activity in this way, it worked for me

```
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
yourFragment .yourmethod();
```

Here 0 is your fragment position.